# Updates always error out

Tags: php, error

Every time I try to run an update, I get these errors. Installing plugins won't work either. I'm using Media Temple / Grid server hosting. I've increased the file size limits in php.ini as well. But I'm at a loss.

```
Status: Internal Server Error
```

Response:

```
PHP Fatal Error 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Out of memory (allocated 226500608) (tried to allocate 4096 bytes)'
in /nfs/c07/h01/mnt/179491/domains/bluepearl.villas/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php:52
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError()
#1 {main}
```

Comment: If you go to Utilities->PHP Info in the control panel and search for `memory_limit` what is it set to? And is that the same value you changed the php.ini memory_limit setting to be?

Comment: Its set to 99M, and the php.ini reflects that as well.

Comment: I just bumped it to 512M, still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Media Temple Grid accounts are limited to 99MB of memory for PHP: https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643740/cgi-and-php-resource-limits

My guess is that they are ignoring whatever values are set in php.ini for memory_limit, but you can contact them to verify.